# Dynamic routing with URL parameters in Spartacus checkout

Tags: spartacus-storefront

What would be the best way in Spartacus to dynamically navigate between checkout steps that are defined with URL parameters? We have two separate checkouts, each having its' own URL parameters for some steps. We need to create functionality that would enable navigating back/next as well as jumping from for instance 5th to 2nd step. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case I'm afraid you would have to override `CheckoutConfigService` and bunch of checkout components to achieve that result.

Current checkout implementation didn't considered multiple checkouts and custom parameters in urls. There isn't any simple extending mechanism for this use case.

Comment: Yes, we figured that would be the case, but had hoped there would be some easier way of achieving this. There is one more problem with this approach however...
As we are reusing payment-form component from Spartacus checkout, we are unable to override its' back/next methods without basically copying the entire component. Any suggestion on how to solve this more efficiently would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [extending checkout](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/extending-checkout/).

Links with steps are made in CheckoutProgressComponent. By default you can go back, but you can override CheckoutProgressComponent.isDisabled method and change guard configs to allow go everywhere. I don't recommend that because it can be not stable if next steps requires data from previous.